# Template matching results when the template is not on the original image

Tags: python, numpy, template-matching

For testing purposes I'm building a bot that clicks on buttons in the screen. I have a folder with all the possible buttons that needs to be pressed and the application being tested only has one button shown at a time. There is no situations where two or more buttons appear together on the screen.

My approach is to take a screenshot every few seconds and loop through all the possible buttons and try to find them on the screenshot. If the button is found the bot clicks the center of the button.

My issue is that even if the button is not present on the screenshot the template algorithm I'm using returns a false positive somewhere in the screen. Is there any way to make sure no false positives are returned unless the button exists on the image?

I'm using python with numpy and skimage. For the template matching I'm using skimage.feature.match_template.

I already tried with opencv using SIFT and all those things with not much success and a lot of issues with opencv itself.

P.S.: If you think there is a better way to solve the problem itself (testing an app by pressing buttons) they are welcome too.

Cheers

**Edit 1:**

These are the images:

[image: screenshot]
[image: button]

**Edit 2:**

The output of the script (false positive)
[image]

Comment: can you please add example images especially for false positive

Comment: @canberk just added them. Also added the output of my script and the false positive.

Comment: The idea I'm trying now is to compare the button image with the suspected area in the screenshot and compute the Manhattan norm, if the images are too different the score will be high and low if they are pretty similar. In that way I might be able to detect the false positives.

Answer (score 1):

As I realised later on, the only way to make sure the detected image is indeed the one you are searching for is to compute the difference between the detected one and the template and use a threshold to allow for imperfections.